# The $post variable – Did I get the grasp of how the Backend actions get parsed?

Tags: metabox, page-template, globals

I was looking for a way to attach a custom meta box to the edit screen of a page at a specific template.

I found and tried this [here](http://www.farinspace.com/page-specific-wordpress-meta-box/comment-page-1) and from my actual point of view this can't work that way. Let me explain why I think so: To determine, whether I'm on a screen using a specific template I need reference the global $post. But since this function to create the meta box is hooked into the admin_init the global $post will not yet exist.

So it has to put out an Error message, doesn't it? After those thoughts I tried to tie my meta_box_init function to edit_post, save_post and such. But the codex says, even they need $post to be set. So how could I achieve my page template specific meta box, really? Is there a clean solution?

Comment: At the very beginning of creating the new post first define a template for it and save as draft.

Comment: But how will that prevent me from getting the messages when NOT actually on such an updated page screen? This does not fix the issue $post is not available at the time when initializing the meta box…

Comment: Simply check current template after post is saved (as draft or any): `global $post; if('your-template.php' == wp_basename( get_page_template() ) {//do metabox stuff here};`.

Comment: As I've noticed your mentioned link also has similar condition: `if ($template_file == 'home.php')`.

Comment: Thanks but your new approach ends up telling me "Trying to get property of non-object in …/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 1275". The problem with the approach I linked to is, that this $template_file already requires $post to be set as well.

Comment: Show us please the code you use to add meta box.

Comment: Well I ain't even got my meta box set up entirely and stick around with simple echoing tries to first find out if my call to it even would work. Like this: if('contact.php' == wp_basename( get_page_template() )) { echo 'Hello';};

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7456/discussion-between-max-yudin-and-circuit-circus)

Comment: i'm afraid it must be there's no solution than attaching the meta box to page edit screens in general and use css display options to trigger its presence in regard to what template is chosen (via param inside add_meta_box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've already wrote in question comments, at the very beginning of creating the new post or page first choose a template and save as draft. Meta box will appear after save if right template is used.

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_meta_box' );
function my_add_meta_box() {
    // get template file name
    $template_basename = wp_basename( get_page_template() );
    // check if right template is used
    if('my-template.php' == $template_basename) {
        add_meta_box(
            'my_metabox',
            __('Metabox name'),
            'my_display_metabox',
            'page',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
    }
}
function my_display_metabox($post) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_metabox', 'my_metabox_noncename' );
    // meta box HTML here
}
```

Comment: Whew, this got it working finally… Thank you very much!